# How to convert a quote to order

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment-methods, payment-gateway

To finish implementing a custom payment method I need to know how to convert the quote to the actual order.

From payment gateway, my custom controller is called.

Inside that controller, I can access Checkout Session object.

When I call `getQuoteId` on that object, I get the actual quote id, however, when I call `getLastRealOrderId`, nothing is returned, so I think I need to do a previous step first.

I have read https://mage2.pro/t/topic/732 and https://mage2.pro/t/topic/731 but those sites only shows code, with no explanation, so I need a little guide to use method calls shown there.

The order should be created in both when failure and success payment occured.

Furthermore, when success payment, the confirmation e-mail for customer should be sent automatically.

How can I do it?

EDIT:

This is a controller that is called using $.post jquery method:

```
class Store extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

/**
 * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
 */
protected $_logger;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 */
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Almacena los datos para posterior recuperacion
 *
 * @return void
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExitExpression)
 */
public function execute() {
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        ----
    }
    } catch (RemoteServiceUnavailableException $e) {
        $this->_logger->critical($e);
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusHeader(503, '1.1', 'Service Unavailable')->sendResponse();
        /** @todo eliminate usage of exit statement */
        exit;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->_logger->critical($e);
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
    }
}
```

Quote Id is received by POST method in execute() function. I need to be able to create the order from there. How can I define the constructor in the proper way? I am thinking that maybe constructor parameters are specified as @params comments, aren't they? I would found this to be strange, since those are comments in PHP, but maybe Magento uses that information to do such a definition.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to try to make it simple and understandable.

So to convert a quote to an order, you need to use the `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface` interface.

Use dependency injection in your constructor to have an accessible variable for this one:

```
protected $_quoteManagement;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $quoteManagement)
{
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    //$this->_quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
    $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Then to convert a quote to an order you can do the following in your `execute` method:

```
$order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
```

Regarding the `getLastRealOrderId` it is not managed automatically by the order creation and thus you need to use your `_checkoutSession` object like this:

```
$this->_checkoutSession
    ->setLastOrderId($order->getId())
    ->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
```

If you need more details about quote conversion I reckon you should have a look at the `saveOrder()` method of `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php`

Comment: This is clear but dependency injection. If I just add a new parameter to constructor, application throws an exception telling that the number or types of parameters are incorrect. I have read several documents about dependency injection but they are not clear enough to understand the thing in practice. How can I define constructor parameters?

Comment: @jstuardo yeah you have to follow the parent constructor order but somehow sometimes it is not clear as you said. Feel free to post your class and I'll help you setting it up.

Comment: @jstuardo I have updated my answer accordingly to your question update

Comment: It was  the same problem I have got before: Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to Desytec\Transbank\Controller\Purchase\Store::__construct() must
 be an instance of Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface, none given

Comment: I call the controller only by calling its URL. Do I need to define something in the XML file?

Comment: @jstuardo no that should definitely work. Try deleting var/cache and var/generation folders

Comment: You were right... it works, however, I have found that the QuoteManagement object has a placeOrder method: public function placeOrder($cartId, PaymentInterface $paymentMethod = null). This method does some things internally and then call submit and returns the order id. It is better to call that method instead? I tried it, but I was required to pass the Payment Method.

Comment: @jstuardo No I reckon you should stick to the method I gave you, I'm not too sure how that `placeOrder` method is supposed to be used

Comment: To call submit method I need a QuoteEntity. PlaceOrder function is getting it, that is why I asked about that function. So, if I use submit directly, how can I get the QuoteEntity when I have only its ID?

Comment: @jstuardo in your OP,  you said you can access Checkout Session object, thus you can get the quote directly doing `$_checkoutSession->getQuote()`

Comment: I did it, however, an exception telling that I need to select payment method just on submit function call was thrown. So, I need to do something similar as PlaceOrder method. How can I get PaymentMethodInterface? can I use the constructor too to get it? is it that magical?

Comment: @jstuardo yeah use the constructor it's not magic it's called dependency injection and yeah it's great

Comment: It was not so magical... now, the error is "requested payment method is not available"... maybe I need to call a select payment method function or whatever... I am calling the controller using an ajax call when the checkout button is pressed (the button that is present when I select payment method), so I thought payment method was present in session but it was not.

Comment: this.getData() in the js that is called when checkout button is clicked contains the payment method, but in json format. How can I pass it to the controller? I tried to convert that json into a PaymentMethodInterface but it was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem with payments. I traced that back to `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment\ToOrderPayment::convert()`:

```
public function convert(Payment $object, $data = [])
{
    $paymentData = $this->objectCopyService->getDataFromFieldset(
        'quote_convert_payment',
        'to_order_payment',
        $object
    );

    $orderPayment = $this->orderPaymentFactory->create();
    $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
        $orderPayment,
        array_merge($paymentData, $data),
        '\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface'
    );
    $orderPayment->setAdditionalInformation(
        array_merge(
            $object->getAdditionalInformation(),
            [Substitution::INFO_KEY_TITLE => $object->getMethodInstance()->getTitle()]
        )
    );
    // set directly on the model
    $orderPayment->setCcNumber($object->getCcNumber());
    $orderPayment->setCcCid($object->getCcCid());

    return $orderPayment;
}
```

It starts by processing the fieldset to copy data from `$object` into the `$paymentData` array, but then feeds that array into `\Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper::populateWithArray()` to actually set the values on the target object (here, `$orderPayment`).

Rather than directly adding the data array to the object as in Magento 1, DataObjectHelper looks for 'set__' or 'setIs__' methods corresponding to each key, and then calls those methods with the value. If such method does not exist, the data key is skipped entirely.

Quote addresses and items are processed the same way, in `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress` and `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem` respectively.

What does that mean?

Adding the key to a fieldset is not sufficient, unless a set method already exists on the object corresponding to that key.
It appears that copying custom fields from quote to order will require either overriding the target class to add the necessary setter method(s) (via dependency injection), or using observers like `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` to copy the data manually.

Also note that the quote module has its own fieldsets defined, including `quote_convert_address` and `quote_convert_item`. It does not appear that the `sales_convert_quote`* fieldsets are in use anymore.

**OR**

For Magento 2 - [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item/ToOrderItem.php) will help you

Answer (score 0):

> If you already have a quote
>
> Simply do following code to convert quote to order

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$paymentMethod = "your payment method code here";
$quote->setPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
$quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => $paymentMethod]);
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();                
$objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface)
              ->placeOrder($quote->getId());
```

**In my case I already had a shipping info and customer/guest info in quote**

Answer (score -3):

I donno how you have implemented your module, but if u already have quoteId, then you can try this once..

PS - Please test this properly before using in live server

```
    $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
    $items = $quoteObj->getAllItems();
    $quoteObj->collectTotals();
    $quoteObj->save();
    $quoteObj->reserveOrderId();
    $quotePaymentObj = $quoteObj->getPayment();

    $convertQuoteObj = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote');

    $orderObj = $convertQuoteObj->addressToOrder($quoteObj->getShippingAddress());
    $orderPaymentObj = $convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quotePaymentObj);

    $orderObj->setBillingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getBillingAddress()));
    $orderObj->setShippingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getShippingAddress()))
            ->setShipping_method($shipping_method)
            ->setShippingDescription($shipping_method_description);
    $orderObj->setPayment($convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quoteObj->getPayment()));


    foreach ($items as $item) {
        //@var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
        $orderItem = $convertQuoteObj->itemToOrderItem($item);
        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            $orderItem->setParentItem($orderObj->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId()));
        }
        $orderObj->addItem($orderItem);
    }
    $orderObj->setCanShipPartiallyItem(false);
    $totalDue = $orderObj->getTotalDue();

try{
    $orderObj->place(); //calls _placePayment
    $orderObj->save();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();

}
```

Comment: The question is Magento 2 and you are given answer magento1